# Performance bottleneck in Tensordot

Tags: python, performance, numpy, multidimensional-array, dot-product

While I was trying to understand [**`numpy.tensordot()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html), I tried out the examples from the documentation and was convinced that we can get exactly same `tensordot`ed result by different permutation of `axes` argument. For example, the below two permutations of the axes are equivalent (i.e. they both yield same result):

```
In [28]: a = np.arange(60.).reshape(3,4,5)
In [29]: b = np.arange(24.).reshape(4,3,2)

In [30]: perm1 = np.tensordot(a, b, axes=[(1, 0), (0, 1)])
In [31]: perm2 = np.tensordot(a, b, axes=[(0, 1), (1, 0)])

In [32]: np.all(perm1 == perm2)
Out[32]: True
```

---

However, while measuring the performance, I found that one permutation is little **over 2x faster** than the other and that puzzles me..

```
# setting up input arrays
In [19]: a = np.arange(30*40*50).reshape(30,40,50)
In [20]: b = np.arange(40*30*20).reshape(40,30,20)

# contracting the first two axes from the input tensors
In [21]: %timeit np.tensordot(a, b, axes=[(0, 1), (1, 0)])
3.23 ms ± 166 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# an equivalent way of contraction of the first two
# axes from the input tensors as in the above case
In [22]: %timeit np.tensordot(a, b, axes=[(1, 0), (0, 1)])
1.62 ms ± 16.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So, what is the reason for the **2x speedup** in the latter case? Does it have to do with how NumPy `ndarrays` are structured internally in memory? Or something else? Thanks in advance for your insights!

Comment: `tensordot` is Python code that you can read.  What you need to do is figure out how `a` and `b` are transformed into the arrays that are given to `np.dot(at, bt)`.  Are they the same in the 2 cases?  Does the conversion take longer in one case or the other?

Comment: `perm3=np.dot(a.transpose(2,1,0).reshape(5,-1), b.reshape(-1,2))` matches `perm1`, as does `np.einsum('ijk,jil->kl',a,b)`

Comment: While `transpose` and `reshape` normally create views, a `transpose` followed by `reshape` may require a copy.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, they are the same arrays in both cases. Please see my test inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Without going into the details, these two calculations recreate the actions taken by `tensordot`, and produce the same `perm` values.

They show the same sort of 2x speed difference:

```
In [24]: timeit np.dot(a.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(50,-1), b.transpose(1,0,2).reshape(-1,20))
4.39 ms ± 103 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [25]: timeit np.dot(a.transpose(2,1,0).reshape(50,-1), b.reshape(-1,20))
2.99 ms ± 97.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

My guess is that the 2nd is faster because the `b.reshape(-1,20)` does not require a copy, whereas the transpose followed by reshape in the 1st does.

And timing the different reshapes:

```
In [28]: timeit a.transpose(2,1,0).reshape(50,-1)
128 µs ± 978 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [29]: timeit a.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(50,-1)
1.04 µs ± 21.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [30]: timeit b.reshape(-1,20)
501 ns ± 14.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [31]: timeit b.transpose(1,0,2).reshape(-1,20)
27.5 µs ± 1.34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

There are significant differences in speed.  `[30]` is just a `view`, so that explains why it is so fast.  I'm guessing `[28]` is so much slower because it involves a full reversal of elements, where as `[29]` copy (40,50) blocks.